# Many floating DIVs same height

Tags: css, html, dynamic, height

I have such situation: http://jsfiddle.net/HKHS3/
The question is how to make `div`s appear row after row where all `div`s in one row have the same height, depending on actual content of the tallest one?

So, depending on `body`'s width the number of `div`s in a row will vary but each time the  `div` right after the end of row should kind of clear floating and start a new row.

Comment: Are the borders completely necessary?

Comment: Border's are for visual presentation but can have some meaning. Why are they concern?

Comment: @friedman: I suspect F4r-20 was asking about the borders because without then you could make it look like it sort of works [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/HKHS3/4/)

Comment: Yes, you are right! Thank you. If the same thing is achievable with borders then it would be great. But floating feature is also a key since the div's at the very end row should stick to the left and the container has text-align: center feature to center whole block on page.

Comment: @friedman: [Here is a javascript solution](http://jsfiddle.net/HKHS3/5/) if you are interested, it uses JQuery

Answer (score 8):

**Fixed number per row**

You can do this by creating a `row` type `div` to wrap your inner `div` elements.

First you need to restructure your HTML, something like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div>abc</div>
    <div>adb djhf kdfhv fkjsh vhf jhds fjhf jh fjhf jh fdjh dh</div>
    <div>dhfjgh jfh gkjhfde jghf jgh jfdh gjfhd gjfdhg jfhd gjdhf jhg djhg jdh gjhfd</div>
</div>
```

(you can add more rows like this as you need to)

Then the following css should do what you need:

```
.row {
    display:table-row;
}

.row > div {
    width: 100px;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 5px;
    height:100%;
}
```

[Here is your example updated](http://jsfiddle.net/HKHS3/2/)

---

**Dynamic number per row (not perfect)**

The problem with the above method is that it requires you to have a fixed number of `div` elements per row. If you wanted it to be dynamic and wrap then you will have a problem doing this with just CSS alone. The closest you could get to it would be as follows:

```
div {
    width: 100px;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
    margin: 5px;
}
```

But the elements do not all have the same height, it is just you cannot tell that without the border. Due to this, adding a `border`, `background-color` or any other style that shows the element's height will break the effect.

[Here is an example of this](http://jsfiddle.net/HKHS3/4/)

---

**Exactly as required (requires javascript)**

It is worth mentioning that the effect you want is doable using javascript. I wont include an example of this because the actually implementation will depend heavily on how your real HTML is set up.

Actually, I had a quick go at the javascript approach, it uses JQuery though, and can likely be optimised too:

```
function updateHeights() {
    var maxHeight = 0, lastY = 0, rowDivs = [], allDivs = $("div"), count = allDivs.length;

    allDivs.each(function (i) {
        var div = $(this), offset = div.offset(), y = offset.top, x = offset.left, h = div.height();

        if (h > maxHeight) maxHeight = h;//store the highest value for this row so far
        if (lastY == 0) lastY = y;//get the y position if this is the first element

        //if new row
        if (y > lastY) {
            resizeElements(rowDivs, maxHeight);//resize all elements on this row
            rowDivs.length = 0;//reset the array of row elements, ready for next row
            maxHeight = h;//set maxHeight to first of new row
        }

        lastY = y;//store current y posible for checking if we have a new row or not
        rowDivs.push(div);//add current element to row collection

        //check if last item, is so then resize this last row
        if(count - 1 == i)
            resizeElements(rowDivs, maxHeight);
    });
}

function resizeElements(elements, height) {
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        $(elements[i]).height(height);
    }
}

$(window).resize(function () {
    updateHeights();
});
updateHeights();
```

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/HKHS3/6/)

Comment: Well... Thank you but it does not really work. As I stated at the start, the number of `div`s in a "row" will vary. These are not set rows like each has 3 or 4 div's. They have dynamic number of `div`s depending on window width. What you did is that you closed 3 `div`s in each row an created a table. That's not it.

Comment: @friedman: Then no, you cannot do it. If they do not have a container element to use to calculate the size then it wont work. You can do this with javascript if that is an option?

Comment: Really would like to avoid javascript.

Comment: @friedman: I am sure you would, but the simple fact is that there are limitations with CSS, and what you are trying to do is one of them

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple using jQuery. For all divs in same row give single class. Lets say 'sameheight' in my example. Then use this jQuery.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var maxHeight = 0;

    $(".sameheight").each(function(){
       if ($(this).height() > maxHeight) { maxHeight = $(this).height(); }
    });

    $(".sameheight").height(maxHeight);

});
```

For multiple rows repeat the code with different class.
Hope this solves your issue.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var maxHeight = 0;
        $('div').each(function () {
            var this_div = $(this);
            if (maxHeight < this_div.height()) {
                maxHeight = this_div.height();
            }
        })

        $('div').css({ 'height': maxHeight.toString() });
    })
</script>
```